# Beancount: Use symbols of ":" to be comment symbols as ; does

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am working on beancount and plan to integrate the beancount accounting and org todo agenda.

```
****** TODO "Learn How to Use Beancount"
;;Skills accounting
2019-09-10 * "Learn How to Use Beancount"
           Assets:Labor -2  HOUR
           Expenses:Applications:Beancount
```

[image]

However, when start to clocking the task as

```
****** TODO "Learn How to Use Beancount"
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-09-11 Wed 00:20]
:END:
;;Skills accounting
2019-09-10 * "Learn How to Use Beancount"
           Assets:Labor -2 HOUR
           Expenses:Applications:Beancount
```

Bean report multiple errors:

[image]

So, bean's syntax does not ignore symbols of `:` and keywords of CLOCK.

How could enable them as comment sysmbols in beancount?

Comment: I have no idea what Beancount is. Adding a link to it in your question might help at least some of us out here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `:` like that because it messes up with Beancount syntax.

The proper way to annotate Beancount transactions is to add either tag or meta to them. Example:

```
;;Skills accounting
2019-09-10 * "Learn How to Use Beancount" #logbook ;<-- a tag.
    clock: "[2019-09-11 Wed 00:20]"  ;<-- a meta.
    Assets:Labor -2 HOUR
    Expenses:Applications:Beancount
```

To transform those transaction entries you create your own custom plugin that looks for `#logbook` tagged transactions and do something with them based on `clock` meta.

Or, if you want to prepare export file for calendar, then create a script that imports beancount library, parsers and filters your beancount file and outputs a custom string.

Answer (score 0):

Add ":" before the CLOCK keyword

```
****** TODO "Learn How to Use Beancount"
:LOGBOOK:
:CLOCK: [2019-09-11 Wed 00:20]
:END:
;;Skills accounting
2019-09-10 * "Learn How to Use Beancount"
           Assets:Labor -2 HOUR
           Expenses:Applications:Beancount
```